# distinct not working

Tags: mysql, sql

sql seems to be my weak point- this query is returning the same row three times- i want it to just return one row- have tried distinct user.user_id and distinct posts.user_id (which is the relation) neither work

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.user_id,
                upd8r_stations.title,
                posts.dated,
                user_data.user_id,
                user_data.delegate_no,
                user_data.first_name,
                user_data.surname,
                user_data.company_name,
                user_data.tel_no,
                user_data.email_addr,
                user_data.rfid_tag
FROM   user_data,
       posts,
       upd8r_stations
WHERE  posts.station_id IN (SELECT station_id
                            FROM   upd8r_stations
                            WHERE  owner_id = '10')
       AND user_data.user_id = posts.user_id
       AND posts.station_id = upd8r_stations.station_id
ORDER  BY posts.dated DESC
```

Comment: Can you show us the data that you're getting back? Seems unlikely that DISTINCT isn't working. I'm guessing it's therefore *not* returning the "same row three times".

Comment: Presumably this user has made 3 posts? (Or has 3 matching records in `upd8r_stations`) In which case what value do you want for `posts.dated` or `upd8r_stations.title`?

Comment: its the same row three times, it's something to do with my joins

Comment: The result won't contain same row three times, maybe there's some different between some column which you can't determine (like some superfluous space).
You use Select Distinct on a rather small set of column, it will be easier to determine data of which column is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISTINCT operates on **all** columns of the SELECT statement.

I guess some of the other columns are different. `posts.dated` or `upd8r_stations.title` seem to be candidates for that.

Comment: i need only the user_data row to be returned unique- need to know every use who has made post at a station belonging to owner 10

Comment: @Chris - So if they have made 3 different posts at different times which `posts.dated` should be returned in that single row?

Comment: @Chris - That's up to you! Why are you including this column in the first place? If you don't need it remove it. If you do need it which value do you want? e.g. the First one, the Last one? All of them concatenated into a delimited string?

Comment: ok, thanks for your think i got it now. i'll just remove the dated field